# Вопросы к неморфологизированным сказуемым

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие вопросы задавать от подлежащего к неморфологизированному сказуемому: к подлежащему (при постановке тире), к составному глагольному сказуемому, составному именному сказуемому? Задавать вопрос "что говорится о подлежащем?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неморфологизированные формы сказуемого выражаются:

1. Неопределенной формой глагола.

   Так ты кусаться, окаянная. (Ты что делаешь?)Кусаться = кусаешься, начинаешь кусаться. А царица (что делает?) хохотать.(=хохочет, принялась хохотать)
2. Междометной (усеченной) формой глагола. Н-р: Хорек (что делает?) за хвост цыпленка хвать. (=ухватил).
3. Фразеологические единицы: Иван Иванович, что с кривым глазом, тоже (что сделал?) приказал долго жить. (= умер)
4. Синтаксически цельные словосочетания. Н-р: Мы с удовольствием (что сделаем?) примем участие (поучаствуем) в посвящении первокурсников.

К неморфологизированному составному глагольному сказуемому - что делается? каково вам (мне, им)? что говорится о ...? что происходит?

(Что происходит?) Надо проехать по этой дороге. (Каковы были ощущения?) Холодно было гулять по парку.

К составному именному сказуемому - Он есть кто?Он был кем?  Он каков? Он казался каким?

К неморфологизированному подлежащему всё-таки кто? что? о чём говорится?